# How to read and create new FoxPro 2.6 database table using Python dbf library

Tags: python, python-3.x, foxpro, dbf

library version: `dbf 0.97.0`, python version `3.5.5`

I am trying to create a new FoxPro 2.6 `.DBF` file with the `dbf` library. I run

```
    >>> import dbf
    >>> table = dbf.Table('test', 'TEST C(40); TEST2 N(3,0); TEST3 C(3)', dbf_type='fp')

    >>> table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "...\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5793, in open
        raise DbfError("Unsupported dbf type: %s [%x]" % (version_map.get(header.version, 'Unknown: %s' % header.version), header.version))
    dbf.DbfError: Unsupported dbf type: Unknown: 0 [0]
```

when I run the open for the second time it seems OK:

```
    >>> table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
    dbf.Table('test.dbf', status=<DbfStatus.READ_WRITE: 2>)
```

however when I try to write some data to the table it gets stuck:

```
    >>> table.append(("Lorem ipsum", 123, "321"))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "...\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5516, in append
        newrecord = Record(recnum=header.record_count, layout=meta, kamikaze=kamikaze)
      File "...\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 2773, in __new__
        record._update_disk()
      File "...\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 3100, in _update_disk
        layout.dfd.seek(location)
    ValueError: seek of closed file
```

If I add a memo field to the table it opens (I don't have to call it twice) and appends correctly.

Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ethan Furman Can you help me please?

Comment: It seems to be messing up the header because the first byte is 0x00 which does not correspond to any DBF version. I also tried a workaround creating the table with a memo field and using `table.delete_fields` to delete the memo field after opening which does not raise any errors but the header is still messed up because first byte is then 0x01 (also no DBF version correspondence there).

Comment: looking into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:  Upgrade to `0.97.2.`

---

Long answer: There was a bug in the header creation of `'fp'` tables with no memos, which has now been fixed.

Note:  `dbf.Table` returns the table `CLOSED`; however, some commands will automatically open and close the table for you:

- the `with` statement
- `dbf.Processing()`
- `dbf.add_fields()`
- `dbf.delete_fields()`
- `dbf.rename_field()`